How to Create & Utilize HTTP Tiggered based WebJob
So i want to create a HTTP triggered based web job . Here is my sample code
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static class HttpTriggerFunction
{
    [FunctionName("HttpTriggerFunction")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        // Retrieve a query parameter (example: name)
        string name = req.Query["name"];

        // For POST request, read the body as JSON
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(req.Body))
            {
                var requestBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
                name = name ?? data?.name;
            }
        }

        // Return a response
        return name != null
            ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
            : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
    }
}

Now the issue is how to invoke this trigger .
I dont find any documentaion related to that
Assuming
APP SERVICE : https://[name].[location].azurewebsites.net/
WEB JOB : https://[name].scm.[location].azurewebsites.net/
I tried to curl both url as
curl -x "https://[name].[location].azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerFunction?name=John"
curl -x "https://[name].scm.[location].azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerFunction?name=John"
but didn't get any result

Assuming you've deployed it to Azure: go into your Azure Portal, find the "Function App" resource, and the URL is shown in the main Overview page. Also, note that you're using the old style in-process Function syntax here; so if you're just starting out on Functions, you might want to learn the later "isolated process" Function syntax instead.

What is the version of your WebApp? Please share your .csproj file

With your code it is clear that you are creating Azure Functions Http Trigger.

You need to deploy this function to Azure Functions and not to the Azure App Service.



To work with Azure Web Jobs, you need to create a console app and deploy it to Azure Web Jobs.


Even MSDoc says the same to use Azure Functions.

The HTTP, Webhooks, and Event Grid bindings are supported only by Azure Functions, not by the WebJobs SDK.


Check the Comparision table of Functions and Web Jobs and Durable Functions as WebJobs.

Thanks @Muhammed Saleem for the explanation.

Microsoft has built Azure Functions on top of the WebJobs SDK and hence they share most of the programming models like the events, triggers, and connectivity to other Azure services.


Deploy and Publish the HTTP Trigger Function to Azure Functions and run the Function URL.



Trigger the Function using default (Function key).


